# How add data into JSONStore IBM MobileFirst

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst, addition, jsonstore

We are new to `IBM-MobileFirst`. We need create,insert,get,delete data in `JSONStore`. So We tried like this:

main.js:-

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    console.log("Bootstrapping Angular");
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){
        angular.bootstrap(document,['app']);
          var collectionName = 'people';
           var options = {};
               options.username = 'pavan';
               options.password = '123';
               options.localKeyGen = false;
               options.clear = false;
               WL.JSONStore.init(collectionName, options).then(function () {
                  alert("OK");
                  WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add([{name: 'carlos'}, {name: 'mike'}])
                   .then(function () {
                       alert("OK3");
                   });
              }).fail(function (errorObject) {
                  alert("fail");
              });
    })
}
```

First We are getting alert Ok next it's showing Error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

We understand insert into table using `add`.Get all records  using `findAll`,delete using `remove`, but problem is add function not working. So tell me what we miss and guide to us.

Comment: Which version & build of MobileFirst are you using ? What platform is this on ? The error you see is because `WL.JSONStore.get()` is returning undefined. Can you move this code outside the promise of the `init` and see if it works. provide logcat/application output f

Comment: @Srik thanks for reply.we are using 7.1 MobileFirst version.Android Platform.yes we move code outside init also still we are getting error

Comment: Can you share sample code that recreates the error